# Changing error messages in django-rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-auth

Whenever I make a POST request with an empty username value, I get the following error message:

```
"username": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
```

I'd like to change this error message to my own custom error message. However, in my User model I try to create a `blank` error message like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True,
                                error_messages={
                                    'blank': 'You have to have a username!',
                                    'unique': "Username has already been taken.",
                                })
```

However, this error message does not show, instead the default error message shows. How can I show my own custom error message? The `unique` error message shows up fine, it's just the `blank` one doesn't show up.

Comment: Do you have a serializer corresponding to the view?

Comment: @JPG No I don't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 
`'required': 'I am alternative of This field may not be blank.'`

**Update:**

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        extra_kwargs = {"username": {"error_messages": {"required": "Give yourself a username"}}}
```

**Update 2:**

```
username = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Please let us know what is your username!'})
```

Comment: you can do it with serializers. I added in my answer

Comment: Do I need to add something in settings.py for this serializer?

Comment: do you use any django forms? I don't understand you use django-rset-ath package.

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm using the Django `SignupForm`

Comment: Then try Update 2 in your signup form

Comment: I want to change the error message in the rest-auth because for JavaScript users that is what I will be displaying when I get the error message through REST. The Django forms is for non-JavaScript users

Comment: You don't have serializers?

Comment: I tried adding the serializer you gave me, but it still didn't work

Comment: how you use this serializsers

Comment: I added it exactly how you told me to. I then put `'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': = { 'apps.users.serializers.UserSerializer', }` in settings.py

Comment: sorry I can't help you further. I will try with DRF and try which I already give you :-(